# How to show large image using Bootstrap or AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I have below code its working fine, but when I use this code in `Td tab` and with `AngularJS`. It's not working.

http://jsfiddle.net/Qhdaz/1/

My Code with AngularJS. It's not working, I want to show image in `div id="big-image"` when I click one of history image

```
<div class="table-responsive">
   <table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover table-condensed mb-none dataTable no-footer" role="grid">
      <thead>
         <tr>
            <th>Update Image</th>
            <th>Date</th>
         </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody class="gradeX">
         <tr ng-repeat="history in joblistCtrl.current_job.history">
            <td>
               <div class="small-images">
                  <a href="{{history.image_path}}">
                  <img src={{history.image_path}} />
                  </a>
               </div>
            </td>
            <td>{{history.datetime | date:'medium'}}</td>
         </tr>
      </tbody>
   </table>
   <div id="big-image">
      <img src="">
   </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
   $(".small-images a").click(function(e){
        var href = $(this).attr("href");
        $("#big-image img").attr("src", href);
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
   });
});
</script>
```

Comment: _Code with angularjs_ then share it

Comment: i share ><img src={{history.image_path}}   its not working...image show but when i clicked ..large image does not show..in <div id="big-image">

Comment: i edit please see

Answer (score 0):

You can set the image path to a variable by ng-click as I have used call largeImage, then set it to your big image. Also, don't forgot to add ng-init for the initial loading.

```
<img ng-init="largeImage=joblistCtrl.current_job.history[0].image_path" ng-click="largeImage=history.image_path" src={{history.image_path}} class="certificate_smallimage" />


<div id="big-image">
    <img ng-src="'largeImage'">
</div>
```